# How to select data from just the year 2008 in SQL

Tags: sql, sql-server-2008

I have problem in my where clause. I'm supposed to select only data from 2008

```
SELECT 
    Count(S.salesOrderID),p.SalesOrderNumber,p.Duedate, status =
        CASE  when p.status =1 THEN 'In Process'
            when p.status =2  THEN ' Approved'
            when p.status =3 THEN ' Backordered'
            when p.status =4 THEN ' Rejected'
            when p.status =5 THEN ' Shipped'
        END
FROM 
    Sales.SalesOrderHeader p 
INNER JOIN  
    Sales.SalesOrderDetail s ON  p.SalesOrderID = s.SalesOrderID AND  
    P.DueDate >= '2008' AND p.DueDate < '2009'
GROUP BY
    p.SalesOrderNumber, p.Duedate, status
ORDER BY 
    SalesOrderNumber DESC
```

Can you guy tell me how I can change my where clause so only data from 2008 can be included?

Comment: @zerkms i get no errors i get like 14000 rows when i'm only supposed to get like 370 rows

Comment: so how are we supposed to guess what is going wrong? Why every question should start with a survey, and why don't you just explain what happens from the very begin?

Comment: @zerkms  im supposed to include all the ordernumber  which are placed in 2008 with the status of te package

Comment: -1: you've asked three closely related questions, but still haven't shared the basics: what are the field datatypes? What are the requirements of what you need to accomplish? The extra records that are returned: what is their value for p.DueDate?

Comment: @JamieF: it's from the `AdventureWorks` sample database - those are pretty well-known and you can easily find those out if relevant. `p.DueDate` is indeed of type `datetime`

Answer (score 3):

Is the datatype of Duedate a DATETIME?  If so then you would want to present qualified dates, not just the years:

```
WHERE p.Duedate >= '2008-01-01' and p.Duedate < '2009-01-01'
```

Comment: still coming up with the same    rows

Comment: Can you show a sample of some of the rows that you're getting that have dates outside the range you specified?  I notice that you're using the date range filter in your ON statement, but not in your WHERE clause for the main query.  Try putting them in a WHERE statement like I provided.

Comment: Did you try moving the date range to a WHERE from your ON clause?